# numpy.power() and math.pow() don't give the same result

Tags: python, math, numpy, floating-point-precision

Is numpy.power() less accurate then math.pow()?

Example:

Given `A = numpy.array([6.66655333e+12,6.66658000e+12,6.66660667e+12,3.36664533e+12])`

I define
`result = numpy.power(A,2.5)`

So
`>> result  = [  1.14750185e+32   1.14751333e+32   1.14752480e+32   2.07966517e+31]`

However:

`math.pow(A[0],2.5) = 1.14750185103e+32`

`math.pow(A[1],2.5) = 1.14751332619e+32`

`math.pow(A[2],2.5) = 1.14752480144e+32`

`math.pow(A[3],2.5) = 2.079665167e+31`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just a questions how the numbers are displayed:

```
>>> result[0]
1.1475018493845227e+32
```

and:

```
>>> math.pow(A[0],2.5)
1.1475018493845227e+32
```

Both ways lead to same value:

```
>>> result[0] == math.pow(A[0],2.5)
True
```

`result` has its own method `__repr__()` that shows numbers differently than the standard Python `__repr__()`  for `float`.